# Vertical Datum Transfromation Using GDAL

Tags: gdal

I have TanDEM-X 90m DEM with horizontal datum wgs84 and vertical datum in wgs84. I want to change vertical datum from  WGS84 to EGM96. I have used  Following code '''gdalwarp -overwrite in_dem.tif out_dem.tif -s_srs EPSG:4979  -t_srs EPSG:4326+5773'''. But in_dem.tif and out_dem.tif were same no change occur   in DEM elevation in out_dem.tif.

Comment: Have you come across this post? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/191565/vertical-datum-conversion-of-a-raster-with-gdal.  Let us know if any of those answers work.

Answer (score 0):

A little late.

```
gdalwarp -q -ot Float32 -wt Float32 -t_srs "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +geoidgrids=egm08_25.gtx" -s_srs "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_def" <DEMfile_ellip> <DEM_in_geoid>
```

make sure the file egm08_25.gtx or egm96_15.gtx you want the DEM in is under /proj.

Comment: My output file still has the same elevations as the input file